# Break out of ReactRouter when there is no match

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

We're sprinkling some `react-router` over an existing multi-page application, intending to slowly transition to a SPA setup. A problem comes up when using `Link` to link to a page that is not (yet) handled by `Router`.

Inside my main switch, I have a fallthrough `Route`, that renders a loading spinner and should take care of redirecting, reloading or whatever is needed to trigger a full page reload of the browser and show the legacy server-rendered page. And this works...

... until we hit the back button.

Regardless of me using `window.open`, `window.location.assign`, or `window.location.replace`, when I hit the back button `onpopstate` happens, the URL in the address bar changes, but as `react-router` isn't active on that legacy page the content doesn't change.

The only working, but dirty, workaround would be to slightly alter the URL (fx add a ? or & character) and use `window.location.replace` to make the browser do a refresh. But that doesn't feel right.

Any help is much appreciated..

Comment: Oh boy. I feel your pain. It's not an option to work on the migration, and just push it to production once it's all ready?

Comment: Maybe using HashRouter instead of Router will help you, because react-router will trigger the change when you hit the back button, it's just a lead

Comment: Thanks, @tholle 3> but that's not an option with the many pages we have. I've considered HashRouter, but the goal is to replace existing pages with SPA lovin' and HashRouter won't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution that works;

```
const initialPage = document.location.href.replace(/#.*/, '');
window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
    if (!isAppPage()) {
        const newPage = document.location.href.replace(/#.*/, '');
        if (newPage !== initialPage) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }
});
```

Where `isAppPage` is a function that can tell if we're in SPA mode, or not.

I'm recording the initialPage and comparing it to the new page, to allow for navigating by #hash without triggering a reload.